# Swift Change statusBar backgoundColor and textColor

Tags: background-color, statusbar, textcolor

ANSWER:

I/ Open Info.plist file -> Add new Row: View controller-based status bar appearance ->Set to [YES]

[image]

II/ Open yourViewController.swift file and insert:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    // Return false -> Show statusBar
    return false
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    // Change status background color
    let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBar") as! UIView
    if statusBar.respondsToSelector(Selector("setBackgroundColor:")) {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    // Change textColor -> While(LightContent)
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```